# Workflow to use for custom wordpress theme development?

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I am starting out in webdevelopment & wordpress, with prior basic knowledge in html, css, js. I want to create a custom theme, based on underscores + bootstrap. What kind of strategy can you recommend?

**Option 1)** Create all pages first with html/css/js and THEN integrate & convert them into theme & wordpress with php.

**Option 2)** Create everything simultaneously, coding directly in my theme folder with html/css/js and php.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hopefully this will help you a little. Realize though, that I am a novice just getting into theme development as well.

That said, I would opt for option (1) in your question, for this reason: You have a step by step process that you can control and some of the best practices have changed from just a few years ago.

I found a tutorial that you may find useful and helpful that I followed and got a basic theme to work. Caveat: It seemed that while following the tutorial some of the examples did not work correctly however after viewing source code on the incuded examples at each step of the way I was able to complete the tutorial and emerge with a working example theme. I learned a lot.

You can find the tutorial at: [MDBootstrap Wordpress Theme Tutorial](https://mdbootstrap.com/education/wordpress/)

There are others that I found in a google search however this was really helpful.

Cheers and good luck!

Comment: Hi thanks for reaching out. That makes sense - I think my problem was/is that I see many tutorials, where the devs do everything at the same time. Option (1) feels more "clean" to me as a beginner - but I guess, when you have many years experience it might slow you down.